# onclick event handler doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveChanges ();">Save changes</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   function saveChanges () {
      tinyMCE.triggerSave();
   } 
   ...
   ...
```

I'm not sure why but when I click on the "Save changes" link then nothing happens and it does not seem to call the `saveChanges` function.

Is there a way that I could remove the `onClick` event from the link and just have it so that the `saveChanges()` functionality is attached to the clicking of the link with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should be in the `global scope`, if it's in an inner scope it's not accessible to the `onclick=...`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function saveChanges () {
      tinyMCE.triggerSave();
   } 
</script>
```

or with **jQuery**:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Save changes</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.btn-primary').click(function(){
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    });
});
</script>
```

---

It would be a good idea to give the `<a>` an `id` like this:

```
<a id="theAnchor"> Save changes</a>
```

Then...

```
$(function(){
    $('#theAnchor').click(function(){
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save changes</a>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
 $("#btnSave").click(function(){
   //Your code for Save changes goes here
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With your existing code, if you want to do down the jQuery route you can bind the `click()` event like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.btn').click(function(e) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is binding the click event to all elements with the class `.btn`. You could use a different selector if you want to be more specific.

The reason your existing code is not working is because the onclick cannot find your function because you defined it inside the jQuery `$(document).ready` function.