# Javascript not executing functions using = operator

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to javascript, so this is a basic question.  I created a simple mp3 player that loads the first song, then plays the next couple songs in an array.  I modified this code that I found on stack, and it works:

```
audioPlayer.onended = function() {
    if(currentSong < nextSong.length-1) {
        audioPlayer.src = nextSong[++currentSong];
        document.getElementById('songTitle').innerHTML 
                                = songTitle[currentSong];
    }
}
```

However, if I try to put the implementation in its own function and call the function that way it doesn't work:

```
audioPlayer.onended = nextSong();

function nextSong() {
    if(currentSong < nextSong.length-1) {
        audioPlayer.src = nextSong[++currentSong];
        document.getElementById('songTitle').innerHTML 
                                = songTitle[currentSong];
    }
}
```

I don't want to rewrite the code every time I want to use the function nextSong().  I have tried calling the nextSong() function from a button inside the tag, for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165332/onclick-event-handler-doesnt-fire), but cannot get the function to call.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common confusion. What your second example is actually doing is running the `nextSong` function and assigning its return value to `onended`.

Instead, you could change your code to:

```
function nextSong() {
    if(currentSong < nextSong.length-1) {
        audioPlayer.src = nextSong[++currentSong];
        document.getElementById('songTitle').innerHTML 
                                = songTitle[currentSong];
    }
}

// Assign the function (nextSong) not its return value (nextSong())
audioPlayer.onended = nextSong;
```